# PadRight() isn't padding at all

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I'm trying to use the String.PadRight method in C#, but it's just not doing anything with the string.

Code:

```
int strlen = 4 - (data.Length % 4);
char pad = '=';
string datapad = data.PadRight(strlen, pad);
```

The string in question is Base64 encoded data, and I need the '=' at the end to pad it for ConvertFromBase64 to work properly.

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY5NDZmZjNlZGUyOTk3ZWExMmVhMDRlNGFhNjYyOWRjZWVhZWZhOTAifQ
```

Comment: strlen must be greater than the length of data in order for it to pad it. Have you tried specifying `data.Length + strlen` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strlen` must be greater than the length of `data` in order for it to pad it. As Grant Winney points out, [PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a.aspx) takes the total width of the string, and not just the number of times you'd like to repeat that character at the end of it.

In the code below, `strlen` will always be less than or equal to 4, which is a lot less than the length of your base 64 encoded string.

```
int strlen = 4 - (data.Length % 4);
```

So really you might want to do this instead:

```
int strlen = 4 - (data.Length % 4) + data.Length;
```

Or just:

```
string datapad = data.PadRight(strlen + data.Length, pad);
```

Comment: Yeah - I literally just figured that out right before coming back to this post. I was reading the documentation on MSDN too quickly. Whoops!

Comment: The pain of assumptions!!! Thanks @sgbj